# MPI Epetra package c++

Tags: c++, mpi, trilinos

I am working with the package Trilinos, in particular with the Epetra part of Trilinos. 
I am making computations with Epetra_CRSMatrices,
but I could not find any mathematical functions for
these matrices.
In particular I need to compute the transpose and
the inverse of an Epetra_CRSMatrix, to calculate
the product of two Epetra_CRSMatrices, and the
product of an Epetra_CRSMatrix with an Epetra_Vector.
Does there exist any standard functions for these operations?
I checked the functions of the above mentioned classes but I found
nothing.

Comment: Perhaps, you'd get a response faster if you send your question to the Trilinos User's mailing list http://trilinos.org/community/mail-lists/. Would be extra nice if you'd post the solution here even if you'll find it elsewhere.

Comment: Trasnposition is not available in BLAS, so probably should be in higher level packages built on top of Epetra.